# Express req.body is in quotes

Tags: json, node.js, post, express

I am trying to get an Express REST API working, and for some reason the JSON body always ends up with unnecessary quotation marks. I am using the following configuration in the Express middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParse.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

And am using

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

To test this. With request body

```
{"name": "New Event", "description": "Hello. This is event"}
```

I get

```
{"{\"name\": \"New Event Thingy\", \"description\": \"Hello. This is event\"}":""}
```

and with body

```
"name": "New Event", "description": "Hello. This is event"
```

I get

```
{"\"name\": \"New Event Thingy\", \"description\": \"Hello. This is event\"":""}
```

Why am I getting these unneccessary characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request probably has the wrong `Content-Type` set. Double-check that `Content-Type: application/json` is set in your request header.